Is there a race condition in the hardware from using a signal as both clock and reset?
What is the synthesis result on this signal used as both clock and reset?
always_ff@(posedge clk, posedge clk_rst) begin
 if(clk_rst) begin
  reg_a <= reg_a_reset_value;
 end
 else begin
  reg_a <= reg_a_value;
 end
end

always_ff@(posedge clk_rst, posedge rst) begin
 if(rst) begin
  reg_b <= reg_b_reset_value;
 end
 else begin
  reg_b <= reg_a;
 end
end

In simulators, both posedge clk_rst would be recognized as the same event and so
reg_b would get either reg_a_value or reg_a_reset_value depending on previous activity on clk.
Is there a chance that the reset would be prioritized over the clock event in synthesis leading to reg_a resetting first and then reg_b always being assigned reg_a_reset_value?


Is there a chance that the reset would be prioritized over the clock event in synthesis leading to reg_a resetting first and then reg_b always being assigned reg_a_reset_value?

No. Whatever synthesis does, it ultimately produces real physical circuits. And any real physical circuit will have a propagation delay from the clock even to its output changing. Furthermore, if this is implemented in an FPGA, the flip-flops are typically designed for "0 hold time", meaning the data is slightly more delayed than the clock signal in reaching the device, ensuring that the flip-flop always takes its input as the value "before" the clock edge rather than slightly after.
In simulation, I can't point you to the relevant paragraph in the SystemVerilog standard that makes it so, but it only makes sense for all the dependent blocks triggered by an event to be evaluated before the output signals of the various blocks are updated. If it weren't this way, you'd get non-physical results from your simulation (which certainly can happen, but you wouldn't want to design your simulator to make it happen in such an obvious use case).

Is there a race condition in the hardware from using a signal as both clock and reset?

No more than in the very common case that two blocks are triggered by the same clock and the output of one is used as the input to the other.

It makes sense that the result of simulations will be most like synthesis results. I am stuck thinking about the reset-Q speed then propagation to D while accounting for possible clock skew. What you're saying is that my concern is already solved by the routing stage?

@snowman, I'm saying that if you are targeting an FPGA, the problem is solved by the design of the routing elements and flip-flops in the FPGA. If you are doing custom VLSI, then you may need to be careful about design, but the HDL tool will not be able to account for that in simulation or synthesis (without adding timing information to the code).
